# Panda: Get row number by comparing value of different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe consist of the following, and want to add a new column based on
high - open < x number
and High.rowNum >= Open.rowNUm

basically I just want to get the first Row Num that match the criteria above and store it as different column

| S/N | High | Low | Open | Close | Date | [New Column] e.g. High - Open >= 85 [Value of S/N] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 20 | 22 | 90 | 1 Jan | 1 |
| 2 | 200 | 40 | 72 | 50 | 2 Jan | 3 |
| 3 | 390 | 20 | 55 | 90 | 2 Jan |  |

Comment: What if criteria does not meet ?

Comment: then, it will be leave as empty or Na.  I have tried to use merge /join table, and filter it out, but the records size is too big. wondering if there is method without merge

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding based on your question and comment, you need 'S/N' in the new column which satisfy the criteria .. so simply you can use `apply` function in dataframe and store result as new column

```py
df['New'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['S/N'] if x['High']-x['Open'] >= 85 else np.nan, axis=1)
```

Here we get new column with `'S/N'` which satisfy the condition else we fill it with `NaN`

Comment: no, the x['high'] is on different row than x['open']. so for each row of x['open'], i want to know which row of ['high'] is greater above z point (e.g. 85 point) from x['open'].   E.g. row 20 the first row x['high'] above 85 point than row 1 x['open']. x['high'] from row 1 -19 is less than 85 point

Comment: Not getting your exact requirements will please elaborate more with data and code which you implimented